# Sparql Select all different languages appear on Warehouse

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I am trying to select all different language tags that appear on a sparql endpoint (like DBpedia) and display them as a list, but with no luck until now.

A simple Example of Triples on Endpoint.

```
<person1> rdfs:label "name1"@en  
<person1> rdfs:label "name2"@fr  
<person2> rdfs:comment "comment"@en  
<person2> rdfs:label "name3"@el
```

The goal is to create a sparql query that returns:
  **fr

  en

  el**

Is there any way to select languages tags efficiently?

Is there a solution for any sparql version(1.0,1.1) ?

Comment: What is a warehouse in your context?

Comment: More idea of what you're trying to achieve, and what you're working with, will help people advise. As it stands, this is such a broad question, it isn't really suited to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your tags include SPARQL, you could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lang
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    BIND (lang(?o) AS ?lang)
}
```